# Can't update Firefox Snap on 22.04

Tags: updates, firefox, snap, 22.04

I tried to update Firefox Snap (from 100 to 101):

```
sudo snap refresh firefox
```

but I got a message that an update was pending, but it could not update because Firefox was running an app, although I did close all Firefox windows and I couldn't find anything with `pgrep firefox`

After a reboot, the update command was working.

So, how do you update Firefox on Ubuntu 22.04 without restarting the system?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with kubuntu.

Comment: I received repeated messages that an update to Firefox was pending, but I ignored them because I didn't want to reboot yet. Closing Firefox didn't stop these messages from repeating, and neither did running `sudo apt update & sudo apt upgrade`. In my case only restarting Ubuntu worked. After rebooting Ubuntu the Firefox snap package was updated from 100 to 101 right away.

Comment: Even after rebooting, the update is not installed in my case.

Comment: I had the same issue, but after closing firefox, checking with `pgrep` that it was terminated, `sudo snap refresh firefox` worked smoothly. I wonder why they chose to move to `snap` with the firefox package. It's all worked so smoothly with `apt` over the past years. :)

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue, but I was simply being neglectful about closing Firefox.

However, I recommend using something like `pkill firefox` or `killall firefox` in the future to see if that'll close all instances of Firefox to stop it from complaining.

Answer (score 1):

Quit the application -- in this case, snap-store (a.k.a. Ubuntu Software). Since snap-store auto-starts upon login, you might not recall that you have it open...but you do.

Closing the window is not enough to terminate the application.

One way: On the command line, run `snap-store --quit`

Another way: Open Ubuntu Software, look at the top bar, find "Ubuntu Software" on the left side of the top bar. Click it, and select "Quit".

Run `sudo snap refresh`. Let the command complete.

If, instead of a refresh, you still get a pop-up that the application needs to be refreshed, then run `sudo snap refresh firefox`.
The output of that command will return the PID causing the block.
Use `kill <pid>` to remove the block.
Run `sudo snap refresh` again. This time it should work.

It's now safe to re-launch your application.